# Can I add a lookup in my batch file that checks the date when the file was created\modified

Tags: datetime, batch-file, variables

Is it possible for a batch file to check the date when a file was created and then copy and rename it to a different folder.

I have got a current batch file that uses the file name, but I would like it to look for when it was created either as well or just the file creation date\time.

The current process is:

The user presses a button on there machine and it creates a file named ZHREPT1 for day 1 ZHREPT2 for day 2 and so on, but it overwrites the 7 files after the 7th day, which is why I need to rename it with a date\time stamp.

A Task Scheduler runs the batch file at 02:00 every morning, that renames it and moves it to another folder.

This is my current code

```
@echo off    
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",0,now) : d=weekday(s)    
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)    
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "mydate=%%a"    
set "dd=%mydate:~6,2%"    
set "mm=%mydate:~4,2%"    
set "yyyy=%mydate:~0,4%"    
set "mytime=%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%"    
set "bckname=End of Day__%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy% - %mytime%.csv"    
echo %bckname%    
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs" /Q    
copy "C:\VPRO\DATA\REPORTS\ZHREPRT?.VRP" "C:\End of Day\%bckname%"
```

I have seen on this website, the below script, but I am not sure if this will work with mine, and where I would insert it (*I havent altered it from the other post*)

```
 @echo off     
 setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

 FOR /R "V:\PPY005\CSC\Script Maker" %%S in (*.scr) DO (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%S" ^& break ^> "%%S" ') do (
         set "line=%%i"
         setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
         >>"%%S" echo(!line:.open=open y!
         endlocal
     )

 )
```

Thank you for any advice that you may have..

Comment: See `attrib /?` and `xcopy /?`. Copy the all files with the archive attribute removing the archive attribute. So a one off `attrib -r -a -s -h "C:\ZHREPT*.*"` to set it up, then each day `xcopy "C:\ZHREPT*.*" "C:\newfolder\*.*" /m /y`.

Comment: That is why the archive attribute exists for - incremental backing up files.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for replying. Apologies for my ignorance can you show me how that would look in a batch file.

Comment: I did. `xcopy "C:\ZHREPT*.*" "C:\newfolder\MyFile - %date:/=-%.*" /m /y`

Comment: Perfect, thanks Mark. Saved me a lot of work, much appreciated. Have a good weekend....

Comment: Programming is about simplicity.

Comment: Barry - The archive attribute is set on a file by Windows whenever a file is created or modified. @mofi Consider that if you ran the xcopy without attrib first once, then you will one by one truncate the existing 6 backup files for the duration of the copy. So briefly those files will not be backed up but everyone thinks they are.